# How to connect Mongodb with Yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2-advanced-app

This is what I have in common/config/main-local:

```
'mongodb' => [
    'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Connection',
    'dns' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
],
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Please edit - what kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

Replace  "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

```
'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo. It should be

```
'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
```

instead of

```
'dns' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
```